# How to find a symmetric matrix that transforms one ellipsoid to another?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, linear-transformations, symmetric-matrices

Given two origin-centered ellipsoids $E_0$ and $E_1$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, I'd like to find an SPD (symmetric positive definite) transformation matrix $M$ that transforms $E_0$ into $E_1$.

Let's say $E_0$ and $E_1$ are specified by SPD matrices that take the unit sphere to the respective ellipsoid:
$$
    M_0 = R_0 D_0 {R_0}^{-1} \mathrm{\ takes\ unit\ sphere\ to\ }E_0\\
    M_1 = R_1 D_1 {R_1}^{-1} \mathrm{\ takes\ unit\ sphere\ to\ }E_1
$$
where each $R_i$ is a rotation matrix and $D_i$ is a positive diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are the respective ellipsoid's principal radii.

Then of course the matrix $M_1 {M_0}^{-1}$ will take $E_0$ to $E_1$, but it is in general not a symmetric matrix (even though each $M_i$ is symmetric), so that's not a solution.

I strongly suspect there is a unique SPD matrix that takes $E_0$ to $E_1$.  How can it be computed?

More generally, if $R$ is any rotation matrix, then $M_1 R {M_0}^{-1}$ will take $E_0$ to $E_1$. In fact I suspect the matrices that take $E_0$ to $E_1$ are precisely the matrices of this form.  So perhaps the question boils down to "Given SPD $M_0$, $M_1$, find a rotation $R$ such that $M_1 R {M_0}^{-1}$ is symmetric".

This comes from a statistics question: given a point cloud in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a target covariance matrix, I want to find an SPD transformation such that the transformed point cloud has the target covariance.  Intuitively, it seems like what's needed is an SPD transformation that transforms the point cloud's error ellipsoid (found by taking the square root of its covariance matrix) to the error ellipsoid of the target covariance matrix; so that's why I'm asking this question.  However, even if I found such a transform, I'm not certain the transformed point cloud will have exactly the desired target covariance;  if it turns out that it doesn't, I'll ask a different question for the underlying statistics problem.

Comment: Huh, looks like the answer to my underlying statistics problem is in this *question*: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113700/covariance-of-a-random-vector-after-a-linear-transformation?newreg=fc66b5f7958749fc93b97bb54f27cb0c   I'm not yet sure whether that yields an answer to the ellipsoid problem though (since I'm not sure it's the same problem).

Comment: Actually I'm now not sure that question solves the statistics problem.  But it does reduce it to finding SPD $M$ satisfying $M C_0 M = C_1$ where $C_0$ are the original and target covariances (i.e. any two input SPD matrices).

Comment: Think about it abstractly. You have two *nonsingular* matrices, and you know of a nonsingular matrix such that when you (pre- or post-) multiply it with one, you get the other. Is that matrix unique?

Comment: @J.M.  Certainly, but I don't see how that helps.  If you think it does, would you please say more about how this corresponds to my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote by $B$ the unit sphere. As $QB=B$ for every real orthogonal matrix $Q$, if we can solve the equation
$$PM_0Q=M_1\tag{1}$$
for some positive definite $P$ and some real orthogonal $Q$, then $P$ will take $E_0$ to $E_1$, because $PE_0=PM_0B=PM_0QB=M_1B=E_1$. Now, $(1)$ is equivalent to $(M_0^\top PM_0)Q=M_0^\top M_1$. Hence we may simply perform a [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) $\tilde{P}Q$ on $M_0^\top M_1$ and set $P=(M_0^\top)^{-1}\tilde{P}M_0^{-1}$.

Note that we do not require that $M_0$ and $M_1$ are positive definite in the above. All we need is that $M_0$ is invertible.

Comment: Perfect.  And it does in fact solve the underlying statistics problem:  $P {M_0}^2 P = {M_1}^2$.

Comment: I notice that the fact that the answer is an SPD matrix that's "close" in some sense to $M_1 {M_0}^{-1}$ gets obscured.  I wonder if there's a way to rearrange the expression of the answer in a way that illuminates this property?  E.g. one might hope that the answer $P$ is the symmetric part of either the left or right polar decomposition of $M_1 {M_0}^{-1}$?  That doesn't work; I just checked, but maybe something with that flavor.

Comment: @DonHatch Well, not sure if this is useful, but we have $P=(M_0^\top)^{-1} (M_0^\top M_1M_1^\top M_0)^{1/2} M_0^{-1}$.

Comment: Or, since $M_0$ and $M_1$ are symmmetric: $P = {M_0}^{-1} (M_0 {M_1}^2 M_0)^{1/2}{M_0}^{-1}$.  Not sure whether this helps or hurts understanding though.  With or without it, the explicit expression seems tantalizingly close to having something cancel out, or to being intuitively meaningful, doesn't it?